# How to stop an ArrayList from being cleared

Tags: java, android, memory, arraylist, memory-management

I am having an Android app which has a list of certain files.

The files are in an ArrayList like this

```
public static ArrayList<File> list=new ArrayList<File>();
list.add("PATH");
list.add("PATH");
list.add("PATH");
....
```

The above ArrayList is present in the Application Class.

The Main problem is that suppose the user minimizes my app for a while till my app is loading the list of the files and the user starts using some other app. After the loading in my app is over the `list` contains the list of all the necessary files. The user returns back after some time, but meanwhile when the user is using other app the Android System is requiring to free up some memory so it clears the ArrayList in my app, as my app is in the recent list and not being currently used by the user.

So when the user returns back he has to wait again till the loading is over.

Is there any solution to this as I don't want to save the ArrayList for ever but want it to not be cleared by Android system.

Comment: how many items are there in the list? The user need those items in a different session of the app also? Those file changes between app different starts or they are always the same?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley There might item can be anywhere up to around 1000. The items should remain same for an App Start but can change over different App Start.

Comment: write the array to a file. upon app startup, read data from that file.

Comment: @ZUNJAE Thanks. But saving the array and again retrieving it might take some time which is not needed by me as I don't want to save them for reuse.

Comment: How long does it take? I'd like to know

Comment: @ZUNJAE As commented before I have said it **might** take some time and I have not tested the time taken. My ArrayList can go up to 1000 values or even more  and saving them and again retrieving them **might** take some time which would be definitely be noticeable on low end deices which I want to avoid. Also writing to a file may or may not succeed due to various reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also serve this use case with Singleton class.

```
class Holder
{
    private static Holder instance = null;
    private List<String> itemArray;
    private Holder(){
       itemArray = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static Holder getInstance(){
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Holder();
        return instance;
    }

    public List<String> getItemArray(){
        return new ArrayList<>(this.itemArray);
    }

    public void addItemToArray(String item){
            this.itemArray.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But will this method protect the ArrayList from being cleared if the Android System need to free up some memory and my app is in the recent list? What will happen to ArrayList if my app is closed?

Comment: Once the app is killed all the instance of Holder class is removed by GC and at the same time, OnDestroy of activity is also called.You need to code such a way that once onCreate is called you need to create an instance of Holder class and add values to the array list.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) .

edit .

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PATH_KEEPER",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();     

//You can use Set<String> or turn into Json and store as String
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();

stringSet.add("somePath");
stringSet.add("somePath");
editor.putStringSet("Path",stringSet);
editor.apply();

//Whenever you want to remove
editor.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks. But as stated earlier by me that I don't want to save it forever. But only don't want it to be cleared. Also will storing a large(1000 size) ArrayList in share preference cause any issue.

Comment: You can clear that data whenever you want.   Anyway, also @Priyank's answer might fit you

Comment: @FerhatErgün Thanks will try out which suits me best.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep list in activity class, and store file path as `String` then this code will serve your purpose:

For String Array:

```
public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("list", list);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    list = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("list");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to use this kind of setup in Application class?

Comment: No, because these methods are part of [activity class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

Comment: Thanks. Will try out this and check which answers method suits me best.